# Message not sent back to client in Java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

The string declared in the client is sent to the server and successfully and printed to the console. No message are being sent back to the client. No error messages to report. Application is just sat waiting. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

ClientWorker thread

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HTCPCPClientWorker extends Thread {

    Socket cwsocket = null;

    public HTCPCPClientWorker(Socket cwsocket) {
        super("ClientWorker");
        this.cwsocket = cwsocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String clientSentence = null;
        // Create input and output stream
        BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
        PrintWriter outToClient = null;

        try {

            do {  // wait for 'QUIT'              
                // Create input stream
                inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cwsocket.getInputStream()));

                System.out.println("\nMESSAGE FROM CLIENT:");

                do {
                    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
                    System.out.println("\t" + clientSentence);

                    if (clientSentence.equals("@@") == true) {

//                      send message to client
                        if (clientSentence.contains("BREW")) {

                             outToClient = new PrintWriter(cwsocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                            outToClient.println("HTCPCP-new 200 OK BREW START command completed.");
                            outToClient.println("Content-length:  " + clientSentence.length()); 
                            outToClient.println("@@"); // terminating chars
                            outToClient.flush();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } while (true);

            } while (!clientSentence.contains("QUIT"));

            cwsocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // end run


} // end HTCPCPClientWorker.java
```

Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HTCPCPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        HTCPCPClient client = new HTCPCPClient();
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE APPLICATION!");
        client.startClient();
    }

    private void startClient() throws IOException {
        final String HOST = "localhost";
        final int PORT_NUMBER = 4444;
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        PrintWriter outToServer = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String serverSentence = null;
        String clientSentence = null;
        BufferedReader inFromServer = null;

        // create new socket
        clientSocket = new Socket(HOST, PORT_NUMBER);
        outToServer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        do {  // wait for 'QUIT'              
            // Create input stream
            inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            // message to send.  Will accept user input later
            clientSentence = "BREW coffee://127.0.0.1/pot-1";

            // Send clientSentence to server
            outToServer.println(clientSentence);
            outToServer.flush();

            System.out.println("\nMESSAGE FROM SERVER:");

            do {
                serverSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                System.out.println("\t" + serverSentence);

                if (serverSentence.equals("@@") == true) {
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
            // read and print message from server

        } while (!clientSentence.contains("QUIT"));

        // close connections 
        outToServer.close();
        in.close();
        inFromServer.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `clientInputLine`? If it doesn't equal `@@` the loop would always read from the client but never return any message nor terminate.

Comment: There does the variable 'clientInputLine' come from?

Comment: apologise.  I have just edited that but to no avial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think After displaying the message from the client , the ClientWorker class checks for the following two conditions

```
if (clientSentence.equals("@@") == true)
```

and

```
if (clientSentence.contains("BREW"))
```

So when these Conditions are true then only the control will enter the inner block and send the message.
So you have to ensure that these two conditions are satisfied.

Here in the first condition you are using equals() method, so if the this condition is true the inner if condition will never be satisfied. So you have to think on these conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the code. To be particular, this part:

```
if (clientSentence.equals("@@") == true) {
//   send message to client
     if (clientSentence.contains("BREW")) {
         // do stuff
     }
break;
}
```

The "do stuff" part is never called, as clientSentence cannot be both "@@" AND contain "BREW".

You also might like to refactor the code a little. It looks complicated. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks.  Redesign is in order